# Difference `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` Width and Height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What is the difference between `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"`
and `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"` for example `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` means that he height will be fixed and the width will be adapted to be same size as height?

Answer (score 0):

**Aspect ratio is a new feature that gives you the ability to specify a ratio between width and height of an ImageView if width and height were set to 0dp, they would be measured depending on the constraints and screen size. For example, if we have an ImageView that takes 0dp for width, height and an aspect ratio of 2:1 this means that the height will always be half the value of the width so if the app runs on a mobile device that measured the image view width 40dp the height will be calculated automatically 20dp.**

**note that you can specify a prefix H or W to tell Constraint Layout which dimension should respect the ratio. If it is H then it means that the width will be first computed from other constraints and then the height will be adjusted according to the aspect ratio. It will be typed as following app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=”H, 2:3".**